# Proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is a model of the induction schema

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How can we show the proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is a model of $$\forall \overline{y} (\varphi(0,\overline{y})\land \forall x (\varphi(x,\overline{y})\rightarrow \varphi(s(x),\overline{y}))\rightarrow \forall x\, \varphi(x,\overline{y})).$$

Comment: Hard to read ... and please explain a bit ... What is y¯? What is ϕ?This looks like a statement about induction, right?

Comment: yes its a statement about induction. ϕ(x,y¯) is a formula

Comment: This is the scheme of mathematical induction? If it is (And if you mean as $N$ the set of natural numbers) then yes, remember that this scheme is an axiom of Peano's arithmetic

Comment: yes. I mean ℕ. how can I prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:\phi(\bar{y},x)\}$ and suppose that $0\in T$ (that is, $\phi(\bar{y},0)$ holds), $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}(\phi(\bar{y},x)\rightarrow\phi(\bar{y},S(x)))$ and $T\neq\mathbb{N}$.  Then, as $\mathbb{N}$ is a well orderd set you can choose $x_o=\min \mathbb{N}\setminus T$. Now, $x_0\neq 0$, so $x_0=z_0+1$ for some $z_0\in\mathbb{N}$. By $x_0$ is the minimum then $z_0\in T$, that is $\phi(\bar{y},z_0)$ holds and then $\phi(\bar{y},S(z_0))\equiv\phi(\bar{y},x_0)$ holds. Clearly, this is a contradiction, so $T=\mathbb{N}$. That is $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}(\phi(\bar{y},x))$.